# For which reason not listed in the guide was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29914666/2436175) was the question.

This was my answer:

> What about a [typedef for your array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array)? Then getting a pointer will be easier.

The user accepted it. The answer has been deleted. I am directed to [a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). The possible reason mentioned are:

> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

So, given that the link was to stack overflow, for which reason was the answer deleted? (And the question, by the way, not... yet?) If there's another good reason, then the guide should be updated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A moderator deleted that post.

I can't say for sure why he deleted it, but without careful consideration or domain knowledge, it *looks* like a suggestion/comment rather than an answer. An easy suggestion to avoid this:

**Don't answer with a question**. *State* what you think the OP should do, change, etc. Don't do so in the form of a question. This is Stack Overflow, not Jeopardy.

Also, including sample code helps. While you didn't have a link-only answer, it still feels very "in another castle"-ish. Having code also makes it feel far less like you are asking the OP something.

Comment: Ok, I see the point, the answer contained a question, yet a rhetorical one. I'll be more careful in future.

Comment: @antonio *"While you didn't have a link-only answer..."* - it's still effectively a link only answer. Saying *"It will be easier if you try [some link here]"* doesn't make it not a link only answer. The only complication here is that it takes a mod's attention because it is the accepted answer.

Comment: @slugster According to the cited guide, link to stack overflow count differently than link to external websites. Technically, there's not a reason to delete because it only contains a link if this points to stack overflow itself.

Comment: @slugster In fairness to that, the link was descriptive. Don't get me wrong, I agree with you that it should have some code/explanation, but I don't think it fits the strictest definition of a link-only answer.

Comment: @Antonio I didn't even bother checking what the link was. *Links should only be a reference*. Besides, SO posts can still be deleted (even though the link will be good) and <10K users won't get all the great knowledge you are trying to share! And if you would just be duplicating that answer, the question is probably a duplicate of it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Not by any mean I am stating it was a great answer, your irony is inappropriate. Either it is decided that deletion is based on rules, or on guts. If the agreement is to decide on rules, than a short answer referring to a SO link is not eligible to be deleted. My answer was also technically a question, so that's the understandable rationale you provided at the beginning that explains the decision of the moderator. I don't understand why you feel the need to go beyond that.

Comment: @Antonio Not really trying to be ironic, more giving you the benefit of the doubt (I truly think you were trying to help!). My point was that a link pointing to SO doesn't really constitute an exception of the problems with link-only answers, since you mentioned that in a comment.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You say `doesn't really constitute an exception of the problems with link-only answers` Not according to the guide, which says `barely more than a link to an **external site**`.

Comment: @Antonio just follow the apples guide. Your answer... is barely an apple. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @BradleyDotNET :) I agree with you.

Comment: Just to be fair, his answer  DID help me. I indeed haven't thought of a typedef and his suggestion helped a lot. I am the guy who asked the question Antonio answered. I understand your points about links but I just wanted to state, in all fairness, that his answer did help me.

Comment: @TheCrafter I don't think anyone is claiming it didn't. The issue is if the answer met our standards for long term usefulness :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeah I know. It just felt right to say it helped!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have edited the answer, now I believe it looks more like an apple :)

Comment: @Antonio Much better and more apple like. Now if only I had some pie...

Answer (score 5):

It was flagged as "not an answer" and deleted as a result. It might have been deleted because the moderator thought it was best as a comment. In fact, you had left a comment with that exact wording at about the same time you left the answer.

People tend to be a little overzealous when flagging answers that are phrased as a question. We're usually able to pick these out and decline the incorrect flags, but sometimes we miss some. We also tend to be primed to convert short answers that only link to other questions or answers into comments. That may have influenced the decision here.

Since it does appear to address the question asked, I've undeleted your answer.

Comment: What can I say differently than the prohibited "Thanks!"? :)

Comment: We are not overzealous! You checked out where that link points to? A Stack Overflow question. If OP considers it's a duplicated, he should have flagged/voted as duplicated.

Comment: @Braiam The question was not duplicated (at least not of the question I linked) because the problem that (that) OP was posing could be solved in several other ways, and using "typedef fixed length array" was just a possible option. I pointed to the question because there were several good answers.

Comment: @Braiam I have edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29914907/2436175).  I believe in this case if you had left a comment (and downvoted if necessary) I would have reacted and improved the answer. I recently got the [shrunk and white badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white). :)

Comment: @Antonio that's how you should have answered. Retracted my downvote.